# Usage of "each" in this sentence

Tags: phrase-usage

I have a question about the following sentence:

> You have each come to me for separate cases. I need to settle this here.

I wonder why "each" is placed between "have" and "come".
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I firmly believe that yes, it is possible! :)

"each" refers to the people who came to him/her I guess. In this case it is used to deal with them both collectively and individually at the same time. So in that sense it could also be rewritten as "Each of you has come to me ...etc" which is equally correct (both in grammar and meaning) with "You have each come to me ...etc"